# compare two arrays having different number of properties and mapping a third array with compared values on condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I have 2 arrays

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

and

```
var array2 = [
  { offId: "4", offname: "four" },
  { offId: "9", offname: "nine" },
  { offId: "15", offname: "fifteen" },
  { offid: "3", offname: "three" },
  { offId: "1", offname: "one" },
  { offId: "0", offname: "zero" },
  { offId: "8", offname: "eight" },
  { offId: "10", offname: "ten" },
]
```

i need to compare two arrays with the values of offId and the resulted array should be

```
var array3 = [
  { offId: "1", offname: "one" },
  { offId: "2", offname: "" },
  { offId: "3", offname: "three" },
  { offId: "4", offname: "four" },
  { offId: "5", offname: "" },
  { offId: "6", offname: "" },
]
```

How could i achieve this(length of the array may be same or different)

Comment: `'offId' !== 'offid'`

Comment: @NinaScholz Both are equal 'offId' ='offId'..edited

Comment: @HKI345 check my answer I think It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and use either the stored object or a new object.

```js
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
    array2 = [{ offId: "4", offname: "four" }, { offId: "9", offname: "nine" }, { offId: "15", offname: "fifteen" }, { offId: "3", offname: "three" }, { offId: "1", offname: "one" }, { offId: "0", offname: "zero" }, { offId: "8", offname: "eight" }, { offId: "10", offname: "ten" }],
    map = array2.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.offId, o), new Map),
    result = array1.map(offId => map.get(offId) || { offId, offname: '' });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

var array2 = [
  { offId: "4", offname: "four" },
  { offId: "9", offname: "nine" },
  { offId: "15", offname: "fifteen" },
  { offId: "3", offname: "three" },
  { offId: "1", offname: "one" },
  { offId: "0", offname: "zero" },
  { offId: "8", offname: "eight" },
  { offId: "10", offname: "ten" },
];

var array3 = array1.map(val => array2.filter(obj => obj.offId == val)[0] || { offId: val, offname: "" });

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: that approach has a worst performance, because you take filter and this iterates all elements of the array. `find` iterates until it founds an element. or use hash table, like an object or a map for fast access without iterating.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to simply `filter()` the second array:

```
const array3 = array2.filter(v => array1.includes(v.offId));
```

That will loop through every element in `array2` and only leave the ones which have their `offId` in `array1`.

If you need it sorted, then just add a sort to the end of that:

```
const array3 = array2.filter(v => array1.includes(v.offId))
  .sort((a, b) => b.offId > a.offId ? 1 : a.offId < b.offId ? -1 : 0);
```

If you need to sort it numerically (i.e., you want 2 before 10), then you'll need to cast the values of those, but then you can just subtract them:

```
const array3 = array2.filter(v => array1.includes(v.offId))
  .sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.offId) - parseInt(a.offId));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` to create `array3` from `array1` & `array2`.

Here are the steps :

- `acc` (accumulated array) will contain the empty array initially.
- Use `Array.find` to check if the `curr` (current variable) is in array2.
- `Array.find` will return the object if `a.offId` matches the `curr` value.
- If `obj` is found, push the `obj` in `acc` (accumulated array)
- Else push the `{offId: curr, offname: ''}` in the array

```js
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

var array2 = [
  { offId: "4", offname: "four" },
  { offId: "9", offname: "nine" },
  { offId: "15", offname: "fifteen" },
  { offId: "3", offname: "three" },
  { offId: "1", offname: "one" },
  { offId: "0", offname: "zero" },
  { offId: "8", offname: "eight" },
  { offId: "10", offname: "ten" },
]

var array3 = array1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  var obj = array2.find(a => a.offId === curr);
  if (obj) {
    acc.push(obj);
  } else {
    acc.push({ offId: curr, offname: ""});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(array3);
```